# ERROR [HY000] [mysql][ODBC 3.51 driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.4.14-mariadb]column 'nofak' cannot be null

Tags: vb.net, oop

[image]

help me ...... I've been trying to find a solution

Comment: Does Labell2 have a text ?

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post code as text and format as code.